# How to make button only activate on double tap on mobile, but activate in single click on desktop?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, mobile

I have a button that triggers a function in javascript. 
This button needs to:

- trigger if you **click it once** (but only on **desktop** browsers)
- trigger if you **tap it twice but not once** (only on **mobile** browsers)

Can this be achieved by html? I am using angular 7.

I have tried to sense if a mobile browser is being used and use a simple "if" in typescript (angular) for processing the click. That didn't work so is there a way to do this with HTML/CSS?

```
//Pseudo code:
if (browser == mobile) {
    register only double tap;
    don't register single click;
}
else if (browser == desktop) {
    register only single click;
    register double click/tap as 2 separate clicks of button;
}


//HTML Button I'm using (this is in Angular 7):
<button id="{{variable}}" (click)="myFunction(param1, param2)" name="on"> 
{{variable}}</button>
```

Comment: [Use a script](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) to determine whether or not you're in a mobile browser.

Comment: @Maryannah I do understand that is a way to do it, but is there no way to achieve this with HTML or other "built-in" solutions?

Comment: Don't know what built-in means in your head, but you have `dblclick` in angular as well as `click`. Simply disable either one depending on the script, and it should work.

Comment: @malbarmawi I'll check soon, I just need to finish up other stuff I started while waiting for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use `click` and `dblclick` to invoke methods base on user mouse action

I have use this method to detect mobile or pc browser

```
export function isMobileBrowser() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

*componenet*

```
  clickHandler(){
    if (!isMobileBrowser()) {
    console.log('Hello from ');
    this.name = "";

    }
  }

  dblclickHandler() {
    if (isMobileBrowser()) {
    console.log('Hello from ');
    this.name = "";
    }
  }
```

*template*

```
<button (click)="clickHandler()" (dblclick)="dblclickHandler()">Log a message </button>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rskvww)  , check this by mobile with this [link](https://angular-rskvww.stackblitz.io/)